# Is it possible to submit a form generated by Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have used this function to fetch some data with help of `XMLHttpRequest()`

```js
function fetchTab1(id) {
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("table_data_1").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    
    xhttp.open("GET", "visit_fetch1.php?id=" + id, true);
    xhttp.send();
}

var id = document.getElementById('member_uniq_id').value;
fetchTab1(id);
```

If the html data I am getting from response text contains a html form, can I submit it?

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't you? Have you tried?

Comment: Here is a question that asks about how to submit a form via JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960240/783510 Does it help you? It uses jQuery though. Not sure if that is a problem in your environment.

Comment: You can for instance do `document.querySelector('table_data_1 form').submit()` after inserting the reply, I'm wondering what the point is though? Submitting a form that was fetched from the server is 100% redundant.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen No that's not my case, my form is generated using ajax!

Comment: I tried, but the submit button doesn't do anything, if I directly put the form code in the main page, it is working!

Comment: @ChrisG Actually I have a pretty big code, I use bootstrap tabs, Now I just want to apply ajax, to split them

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sv18a4ct/  Just from a quick test, the form has to be in the DOM for the submit to work.  You can't just have it in a DOM Fragment.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how the fact that you're using bootstrap tabs relates to your question or my comment. Submitting a form will a) send data to the server then b) navigate to the reply. This is almost guaranteed to be an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 0):

So I came to find out that when I use td (Because put the form fields in columns of a table) I tag inside a form it is not working, but when I removed them, it started to work.